# Redux toolkit typescript -- what is my PayloadAction type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to write a slice for RTK and I'm not sure what the type of my payload should be. My state -- `InviteeState` is an array of people objects

```
interface InviteeState {
  people: {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    url: string,
    note?: string
  }[]
}
```

Then I'm setting my `initialState`

```
const initialState: InviteeState = {
  people: [], 
}
```

And in my slice:

```
export const inviteesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "invitees",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // method to update state
    addInvitee: (state, action: PayloadAction<"people"[]>) => {
        state.people.push(action.payload)
    }
  }
})
```

But In the `state.people.push(action.payload)` line the `action.payload` is throwing the error

"Type '"people"[]' is missing the following properties from type 'WritableDraft<{ name: string; age: number; url: string; note?: string | undefined; }>': name, age, url"

I'm not sure if my `PayloadAction<"people"[]>` type is wrong or if my `inistialState` is wrong also.

How do I know what the correct type should be?

Comment: it should be `{name: string,age: number,url: string,note?: string}`

Comment: Is there a way to set that as a variable so i dont have to type out each property? I thought thats what the state var was for. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you should change your interface to type, then the type of PayloadAction is `InviteeState["people"][number]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your payloadAction should be person object.

First declare the type for "people":

```
interface Person {
    // properties
}

interface InviteeState {
  people: Person[]
}
```

Then the initial state would be:

```
const initialState: InviteeState = {
  people: Person[] = [], 
}
```

You can use `Person` in your slice:

```
export const inviteesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "invitees",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // adding Person to state tree
    addInvitee: (state, action: PayloadAction<Person>) => {
        state.people.push(action.payload)
    }
  }
})
```

You can call that action like:

```
let person:Person // of course with actual data in this

dispatch(
    addInvitee(people)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's helpful. -- I think the PayloadAction type is Person though, not Person[] -- so PayloadAction<Person>

Comment: OK, I modified it. I thought you'd like to push multiple Person to state. Btw you can also push multiple Person by concatenating the people array, in the slice.